# Error in importing flat file in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, flat-file

While using **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard** I got this error message:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "abc" returned status value 4 and status text
>   "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
>   target code page.".

I have set data type as text stream (in advance setting). Which was the problem  in many cases that I have read so far but it didn't solved my problem. Can anyone having experience with it please tell what is wrong with it?

My flat file i.e. text file's data is in following format

```
b_n     b_u
1       www.abc.com
```

(Here `b_n, b_u` is the name of columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Both Properties needed to be changed as text and I was leaving one as string.It might be helpful for others :)